# Convert single column data to multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with only 3 service types I want to pivot only Service type column and show

```
ServiceID   FName  LName Servicetpe
1             A      B      ST1
1             A      B      ST2
2             g      e      st1
3             f      h      st1
3             f      h      st2
3             f      h      st3
```

The output should be

```
ServiceID   FName  LName    ST1     ST2     ST31
1             A      B      X        X
2             g      e      X
3             f      h      X        X       X
```

I tried pivot didn't work with out aggregate function.

Answer (score 2):

You can do conditional aggregation :

```
select ServiceID, FName, LName,
       max(case when Servicetpe = 'ST1' then 'X' end) ST1,
       max(case when Servicetpe = 'ST2' then 'X' end) ST2,
       max(case when Servicetpe = 'ST3' then 'X' end) ST3
from table t
group by ServiceID, FName, LName;
```